# Checking out tags from the local clone

Tags: git

I have following directories src/linux which is a clone of the linux kernel repo. Now while handling different kernel bugs - I would like to checkout the specific tag from this clone to build directory

something like

```
build/linux-3.12
build/linux-3.11
```

Is it possible to do this very fast from the clone which I have locally instead of always checking out the tag from the remote repo ?

Comment: What command are you using to check out the tag from the remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to clone the remote repository to have a second clone locally. Just clone your local copy. This will have the added benefit of hard-linking shared objects (i.e. it saves space).

   ```
   git clone src/linux build/linux-X.Y
   ```
2. In theory, you can ask git to checkout a tag to a different work tree. This can be done using the `--work-tree` option.

   ```
   git --work-tree ../../build/linux-X.Y checkout vX.Y
   ```

   This may require some more force flags or creating the target work tree beforehand and may confuse git when switching back to the original work tree. Use with care.